# Implementing seeking a media file using JSlider in a Swing-based application

Tags: java, swing, jslider

I'm creating a simple media player using jlGUI and jAudiotagger libraries.

I've used a JSlider to implement an automatically moving indicator, as the playback progresses.

Now, I have to implement seeking the file by dragging, by registering that slider to generate events.

So the problem is, when register the seeker, the automatic seeking of the slider(while playing) also causes a ChangeEvent, so its seeking to its own position again and again.

How do I implement it?

Comment: One alternative that I use is to offer a `JProgressBar` instead of a slider.  Add a `MouseListener` to the progress bar to allow the user to 'seek' to that position.  Add a tool-tip that shows where in the media they would jump to (on click) and the job is basically done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about creating a `ChangeListener` which lets you turn it on and off with a method call?

So when you're in *animation mode* it ignores the `stateChanged()` events.

When the user clicks on the `JSlider` (recognize that with a `MouseListener`), stop the animation and call `MyChangeListener.setAnimationMode(false)` so that your listener will react to user interaction.

```
public class MyChangeListener implements ChangeListener
{
  boolean animationMode = true;

  public void setAnimationMode( boolean mode )
  {
    this.mode = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent arg0)
  {
    if ( !animationMode )
    {
      // do stuff
    }
  }
}
```